# Table headings for a single column of data?

Tags: list-manipulation

Is there a way to get this to work?

```
data = {2, 1, 4, 3};
TableForm[ data, TableHeadings -> { {"L1", "L2", "L3", "L4"}, {"data"} } ]
```

Comment: Do `data = List /@ {2, 1, 4, 3};`

Comment: This is another way of doing what @march suggests:  `data = { {2,1,4,3} } // Transpose`.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is also useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find this [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Answer (score 3):

Reformat your data like-so:

```
data = List /@ {2, 1, 4, 3};
```

Then,

```
TableForm[ data, TableHeadings -> { {"L1", "L2", "L3", "L4"}, {"data"} } ]
```

yields

[image]